# F5 load balancer over https url

Tags: f5

I have a service exposed over 2 nodes, each node has a https url for the service.

I want to put a F5 on top of these 2 https nodes, is it possible

Comment: Of course it is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. First create an https monitor, some request that when you get the right response back, the node is 'online'.  Then create a pool with the two nodes (listing their IP and port number) and attach the monitor.  Then create a virtual server or two (I normally make an http one with no pool and the built-in https redirect iRule) plus the https virtual server. give them the same IP address, allow all source addresses (the source here is what allows the F5 to select it, you can restrict IP addresses further with the firewall policy).   Auto SNAT will make the f5 replicate the request to the backend server but with the src IP of the F5.  If you care about the client IP address on the backend servers they will need to listen for x-forewaded-for header.  You'll need to add a profile to the https virtual server to attach such a header and populate it with the clients 'real' src IP.  Then attach the pool and make sure the VS firewall is open correctly.  You'll also need to import the right certs and keys and create an ssl profile that matches the DNS name you want to point at this VS, and attach the ssl profile to the https vip in the client ssl section.  the server ssl section is normally ssl-insecure-compatible.
for the DNS name, hopefully your 2 nodes are named something like web1 and web2.example.com. so the DNS name for the vip should be web.example.com and the SSL Cert required would be for web.example.com or *.example.com if you're feeling frisky lol.